# How can I get the controller type when implementing a custom route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am implementing a custom route and the method *GetVirtualPath* receives a *RequestContext* and a *RouteValueDictionary*

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
}
```

I want to know if the target controller contains some attribute, so far I have found two ways of getting the controller type:

```
var f = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
var controller = f.CreateController(requestContext, values["controller"].ToString());
var type = controller.GetType();
```

I don't like this way because it actually creates the controller. I decompiled the CreateController method and I found it had an internal method *GetControllerType*, that is the second way:

```
var f = new DefaultControllerFactory();
var method = f.GetType().GetMethod("GetControllerType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var type = method.Invoke(f, new[] { requestContext, values["controller"] }) as Type;
```

I don't like this way either because it uses reflection.

Is there a better way of getting the controller type?

Thanks

Comment: Controllerbuilder uses servicelocator this means you only know the type during runtime. Therefore  controller factory cannot provide this during design time.